# How to delete delete a folder from C:\Users\... via a script

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete a folder from C:\Users for any user profile within the Users directory. 
I’m needing help putting together a windows batch script to accomplish this.
The folder stores a user config file for an application that needs to be deleted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dir /b /ad c:\users\ |find /v "["` might give you a start

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

```bat
@Echo Off
(Set UPD=C:\Users)
(Set UDS=SomeDir\TheDir)
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/AD-R-H "%UPD%"') Do (
    If Exist "%UPD%\%%A\%UDS%\" RD/S/Q "%UPD%\%%A\%UDS%")
```

Just put the path and folder spec within the parentheses on line three